# Can I edit an answer without bumping the question?

Tags: support

I just made a very minor edit to my answer to this question: [Can a creature swap places with another willing creature on their turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91161/can-a-creature-swap-places-with-another-willing-creature-on-their-turn). My only changes were syntax, changing hyphens to em-dashes. As such, I don't think my changes add enough value to justify improving it's position in the active questions queue. Is there a way to make minor edits such as these without pushing it up in the active questions queue?

Comment: Relevant: [Why are minor edits discouraged?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4997/4398); [Why do question/answer edits bump a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278143/244929); [Is there a way to edit a question without bumping it to the front page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23241/244929); [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567/244929); [Let experienced users silently edit their posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117332/244929).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the tl;dr is: no.  I believe that the community managers had a way of doing this a long time ago, but that was never made publicly available.

Basically, if the edit doesn't actually add anything content wise to the post, or make it better in general, then it's best to just leave it as-is.  In particular, the edit you're talking about, imho was pointless and didn't help your answer.

Comment: One thing I would add is that while the conversion of hyphens to dashes alone doesn't warrant the bump, if you can find other things that need changing in the post *or in other posts attached to (and including) the question* then making the hyphen-edit "does no harm" vis-a-vis the active questions queue.

Comment: Also if it was already recently bumped/posted don't worry about it-- extra bumps in a short time is no big deal.